# Генератору не удалось создать источник. FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net

Как добавить внешнюю библиотеку NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp в source generator проект c#?

В дебаге происходит следующая ошибка: "Генератору не удалось создать источник. Это не повлияет на выходные данные и ошибки компиляции, которые могут возникнуть в результате. Тип возникшего исключения: "FileNotFoundException", сообщение: "Could not load file or assembly 'NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp, Version=13.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2d88086e098d109'. Не удается найти указанный файл."

Структура проекта:

- G.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>Generator</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.3.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4" PrivateAssets="all" />

        <PackageReference Include="NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp"
                          Version="13.20.0" 
                          PrivateAssets="all"
                          GeneratePathProperty="true"/>

        <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" 
              Pack="true" 
              PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" 
              Visible="false"/>
        <None Include="$(PKGNSwag_CodeGeneration_CSharp)\lib\netstandard2.0\*.dll"
              Pack="true"
              PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" 
              Visible="false"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <GetTargetPathDependsOn>
            $(GetTargetPathDependsOn);GetDependencyTargetPaths
        </GetTargetPathDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="GetDependencyTargetPaths">
        <ItemGroup>
            <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker
                    Include="$(PKGNSwag_CodeGeneration_CSharp)\lib\netstandard2.0\NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp.dll"
                    IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

- G\Properties\launchSettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "Generators": {
      "commandName": "DebugRoslynComponent",
      "targetProject": "../GenTest/GenTest.csproj"
    }
  }
}
```

- и сам генератор